# Jmeter one variable from JDBC for one user in HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

I have JDBC request, what give me 10 values. Also i have ThreadGroup from 10 user. I need launch HTTP request in my service, but for different user i need different value from me JDBC. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you post some of you relevant code?

Comment: this is my sql code 
select id 
from card
where  rownum <= 10

Comment: And the architecture is as follows: ThreadGroup,jdbc request,debug PostProcess,Http request,debug PostProcess

Comment: i think it should be like:${id_${counter}}

Answer (score 0):

Define "Variable Name" in the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler like:

[image]

It will give you the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (observable by the Debug Sampler):

```
foo_1=xxx
foo_2=yyy
foo_3=zzz
...
foo_#=10
```

[image]

Now you can access a different variable with the different JMeter virtual user using [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functions combination like:

```
${__V(foo_${__threadNum},)}
```

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And how can i get data from Sampler Result Error Count?